# Elasticsearch finds only numerical values

Tags: elasticsearch

Good morning, everyone!

With elasticsearch, I can do this request which allows me to have all the profiles for a certain `phone_user`, it works:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/companyname/projectname/_search?pretty' -d '
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":{"terms":{"phone_user":["33612345678"]}}}}}'

{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "companyname",
        "_type" : "projectname",
        "_id" : "113",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "phone_user" : "33612345678",
          "status_user" : "READY",

          ……

        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, if the value is no longer a number but text, I no longer have any results:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/companyname/projectname/_search?pretty' -d '
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":{"terms":{"status_user":["READY"]}}}}}'

{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

My mapping :

```
{
  "conpanyname" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "projectname" : {
        "properties" : {
          "phone_user" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "status_user" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have you ever faced this kind of problem before?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index? Maybe field `status_user` is analyzed and field `phone_user` is not_analyzed.

Comment: Done @AshwaniShakya ! Nothing weird.

Answer (score 0):

As `status_user` is an `analyzed` text field you can either :

Make an exact request with [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) on the keyword subfield or make a [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) (with potential text analysis) on the text field. But you have to choose :D

so for an exact matching

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "status_user.keyword": [
            "READY"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "status_user": "READY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```